# How to remove other user's application in WSO2 api Manager 1.7 by admin

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have admin rights in my wso2 api manager. But it has number of users and they have number of applications which are created by them selves. But I need to remove some selected applications which are already created(approved) by other users also as the admin. So how can I do this in WSO2 api manager 1.7 with GUI. I can do this from the data base level. But looking for a way of doing it with GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not delete or update other use's applications in the wso2 APIM with the graphical user interface up to now even for the system admin. It's not a good practice of deleting other user's account even by the admin. But there can be some practical scenarios in some cases such number of applications are created by different users but no one is using any of them. In such a situation the only possible way of removing those unwanted applications from APIM is, remove them from database. 
We hope this simple feature will also be given with GUI in future.

Answer (score 0):

Check the api store's api at https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Store+APIs

There is an option to delete an application. But, AFAIK, it wont check whether that application has any active subscriptions (APIM versions such as 1.9.0 checks it). So, this can cause problems to existing subscriptions, if any.

Comment: in this link it shows how to remove those applications through api calls. But my question is how do I do it with GUI? Is it available in wso2 apim 1.7

Comment: Its not available in any of the released versions so far. Its wrong to delete applications of other users after they have been created and subscribed. What you should do is, have an approval process associated with app creation or subscription tasks by using the workflow extensions.

Comment: Yah your reason is ok. But there are some practical scenarios to do such a things atleast in rare situations also. Anyway looking that feature in the next releases. Thanks